# Theoretical key encryption question

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

I have a question regarding encryption and message sending.

There are 2 hosts, A and B with their own secret key kA and kB (assuming this is not PKI).

It is known that when A wants to send a message to B, they do this handshaking protocol:

```
A sends to B, an encrypted message in this form E(kA, m), where m is the message and kA is used to encrypt it.

B sends to A, an encryption of the previously sent message, E(kB, E(kA, m)), encrypted using kB.

A will then send to B, E(kB, m).
```

after that, B will just decrypt the message using kB.

My question is that how does A know B's key to encrypt the message.

**What I think I know about the question:**

-I believe it's some kind of mathematical property like RSA's modulus?

-I think it can also be a logarithmic function? (bring down the power, where power = key?)

-Both A and B do not know about each other's key so I think it can be something using interchangeable functions like Log(Exponential(x)) = Exponential(Log(x))?

There's no one real answer as this is just theoretical so I hope to have suggestions (or links where I can further read up) from you guys on how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will absolutely need to do a key exchange so that A knows Kb and B knows Ka. There are different methods but they are usually based in the [Diffie Hellman algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange).

For convenience I will paste here wikipedia's example:

```
Alice and Bob agree to use a prime number p = 23 and base g = 5.
Alice chooses a secret integer a = 6, then sends Bob A = ga mod p
    A = 56 mod 23
    A = 15,625 mod 23
    A = 8
Bob chooses a secret integer b = 15, then sends Alice B = gb mod p
    B = 515 mod 23
    B = 30,517,578,125 mod 23
    B = 19
Alice computes s = Ba mod p
    s = 196 mod 23
    s = 47,045,881 mod 23
    s = 2
Bob computes s = Ab mod p
    s = 815 mod 23
    s = 35,184,372,088,832 mod 23
    s = 2
Alice and Bob now share a secret (the number 2) because 6 × 15 is the same as 15 × 6.
```

You will [find several answers discussing this algorithm](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=diffie%20hellman).

Comment: Hi, I didn't look into diffie hellman's algo, but I shall do it now, but this question comes with restrictions i.e. no prior knowledge of any common info beforehand, A does not know kB, all he knows is the message and kA so that he can do E(kA, m)

Comment: If they can communicate they can exchange some messages with the numbers don't you think? Also, if they can't exchange the keys, they can't crypt their communications...